# Python - how to remove rows with the first two letters in the string and numbers

Tags: python

I have a data frame that has a column with string values. However, some strings start with two numbers and I want to remove them. In the below example, I want to remove row 1 as the first two letters in the string are actually numbers and want to keep row 2. My data set is large and looking for all combinations from 0 to 9 for letters at positions 0 and 1.

```
  col1      col2 
1 CAL101    3701
2 MAU46     3BNBD
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you're looking for. Firstly, sweep through rows using the index, then using `isnumeric` check if the first two `[:2]` items in `any` values are numbers. If they are drop that row from the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
row1= ['CAL101',3701  ]
row2= ['MAU46', '3BNBD']
df = pd.DataFrame([row1,row2])

for i in df.index:
    row = df.loc[i].values
    if any([str(var)[:2].isnumeric() for var in row]):
        df = df.drop(index=i)
```